# Writing simple console chat program

Tags: java

So. Im writing this simple chat program, and basically how it works now that the client and the server takes turn in writing a message. Now i want the client and the server to be able to send multiple messages in a row instead of waiting for the counterpart.

Any suggestions as to how i can send multiple messages, and also recieve multiple messages.

I am new to network applications.

Run method of Client:

```
public void run(){
    while (true){
        System.out.println("Write message to server:");
        String besked = scanner.nextLine();
        oos.writeObject(besked);
        System.out.println("MEssage from server: " + (String)ois.readObject());
        oos.flush();
    }   
}
```

And the run method of the Server:

```
  public void run() {
      while(true){
              String s = (String)ois.readObject();
              System.out.println("Message from client: " +s);

              System.out.println("Write back:");
              String returbesked = scanner.nextLine();
              oos.writeObject(returbesked);
              oos.flush();
       }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two threads, (for each side of the connection) one reads data from the socket and other writes data to the socket. When server accepts client connection, it creates two threads (in the code example they are called **Reader** and **Writer** threads). While writer thread continuously gets some data from a source and outputs the data to the socket,at the same time reader thread  keeps reading data from the socket. Input and output streams of a socket connection are independent of each other so they can be concurrently used.

In the below code I tried to realize the server side but it is pretty much the same for the client side as well:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Server server = new Server();
        server.start(100);  // server port no 100
    }

}

class Server {

    /**
     * Thread that continuously reads data from socket.
     */
    private Thread reader;

    /**
     * Thread that continuously writes data to socket.
     */
    private Thread writer;

    /**
     * Start server
     * @param port
     * @throws IOException
     */
    void start(int port) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket srv = new ServerSocket(port);

        // Wait for client connection
        Socket clientSocket = srv.accept();

        // Client connected
        startReadingAndWritingData(clientSocket);
    }

    /**
     * Starts reader and writer threads.
     * 
     * @param socket
     *            client socket
     * @throws IOException
     */
    private void startReadingAndWritingData(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(
                socket.getInputStream()));

        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()));

        ReaderThread reader = new ReaderThread(ois);
        WriterThread writer = new WriterThread(oos);
            reader.start();
            writer.start();

    }
}

class WriterThread extends Thread {

    private ObjectOutputStream oos;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param oos
     */
    WriterThread(ObjectOutputStream oos) {
        super();
        this.oos = oos;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String output = getNextOutput();
                oos.writeObject(output);

                Thread.sleep(1000); // Wait before sending next String
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /*
                 * Socket IO or serialization error
                 */
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get output String from somewhere eg. file.
     * 
     * @return output
     */
    private String getNextOutput() {
        // TODO get output String from somewhere
    }

}

/**
 * Reader thread.
 * 
 */
class ReaderThread extends Thread {

    private ObjectInputStream ois;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     * 
     * @param ois
     */
    ReaderThread(ObjectInputStream ois) {
        super();
        this.ois = ois;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                String input = (String) ois.readObject();
                handleInput(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /*
                 * Socket IO or deserialization error
                 */
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle received input String.
     * 
     * @param input
     */
    private void handleInput(String input) {
        // TODO handle input

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Some further questions:

How do i actually recieve / Send the messages? in the run method? if so, how do we separate the two run methods?

Comment: readObject() and writeObject() methods do the actual reading data and writing data to-form the socket.

Comment: One more thing, for reading-writing Strings you don't need to use Object streams (object serialization). It is better to use InputStreamReader and OutputStreamWriter to read and write character data to-form the socket. It is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either need two connections, one on which the client writes and one on which the server writes, or you will need to use nonblocking connections, i.e. NIO.